# Creating a stackoverflow-like website

Tags: support, so-engine

We have a successful SDK for which we would like to create a Q&A forum, and naturally we *love* SO. Is there a way to create a stackoverflow-like website for my own SDK purposes for Q&A?

I see there are 105 stack-exchange websites, but I guess they're all owned and managed by stack-exchange... Is there a way to create another one for my company's purposes?

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate question somewhere...

Comment: Very heavily related and probably an alternative dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: What about simply creating a tag on [so] for questions about the sdk? Your support team and developers can simply subscribe to that tag and get notified of new posts.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange source code is not available. There are two ways to use it:

1. Create a site through the official [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) site proposal process.
2. Contact the team directly about an enterprise license. However, this is only available for internal use, not for public sites on the Internet.

Otherwise, you'll have to roll your own solution. Check [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) for some ideas on how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Topics that are of broad public interest can be proposed on the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) site if you wish to see topical QnA on that topic to be part of the SE ecosystem. However the SE engine that powers these sites is proprietary.

If you'd like to run your own site for a company's private interest, you might be interested in [various software projects](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that work work similar to SE.